# What approximations are involved in STFT of a convolution?

Tags: impulse-response, stft, approximation

I have two equations in time domain:
$$x_k(t)=\sum_{i=1}^N s_i(t)\star h_{ki}(t)+n^a_k(t)$$
and 
$$x_k(t)=\sum_{i=1}^N s_i(t)\star h_{ki}(t)\star n^c_k(t)$$ 
which explain the additive and convolutive noise models for recorded sounds in microphones when $N$ sources are available.

Using the [short-time Fourier transform (STFT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) I will have:

$$
X_k(m,f)=\sum_{i=1}^{N} S_i(m,f)\cdot H_{ki}(f)+N^a_k(m,f)
$$ 
and
$$X_k(m,f)=\sum_{i=1}^{N} S_i(m,f)\cdot H_{ki}(f)\cdot N^c_k(m,f)$$

I assumed that the mixing system, $H(f)$ is time-invariant. 
What are the other approximations? The only thing I can think of is that impulse response, $h(t)$ is shortened to the window length in the STFT process.

Regards,
Ati

Comment: You can include the window function centered around $m$ explicitly in your equation for $X_k(m,f)$. Then there are no approximations.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, it seems that there are some approximation as I am asked about them :-)